# How to turn Keep Alive on using php.ini

Tags: php-ini, php

I have a Wordpress site and would like to turn Keep Alive on. I attempted to edit .htaccess file by adding following code:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Connection keep-alive
</ifModule>
```

Because it didn’t take any effect I contacted my hosting company. I was informed that their server configuration requires editing php.ini file in order to have Keep Alive turned on. I was googling for a while but was unable to find anything about how appropriate code, with Keep Alive declaration, in php.ini looks like. Searching through the list of php.ini directives didn’t lead me to anything similar to `Keep_Alive = on`. Could anyone please help me with this. Any clues will be appreciated. Regards,

Comment: did you try with capital I? ```<IfModule mod_headers.c> Header set Connection keep-alive </IfModule>```

Comment: Yes, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

My question is outdated already. Clearly I was misinformed yesterday by the consultant. The real problem is that my hosting plan doesn’t allow to have the Keep Alive turned on. Sorry I was bothering you. Regards